# Smsmanger.sendtextmessage not working on some devices

Tags: android, smsmanager

I developed a program that sends message to selected contact list from a foreground service. The application works perfectly on my device(Xiaomi redmi note 4) but when i tried the same app on Xiaomi redmi 2 prime the code is executed without any error but the message is not sent.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(temp[i], null, msg, pendingIntent, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the runtime permissions. In the device with old android version even though it asks for permission during installation it asks every time when that feature is provoked but i granted those permission manually in the settings and now it works.